# React native splash screen localization

Tags: react-native, localization, splash-screen

I am interested in splash screen localization, e.g. if a device's language is English the app should start with an English splash screen; if a device's language is French the app should start with a French splash screen. Any other language should default to English.

Most blogs mention localization in apps as string files, but I need localization for splash screens.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of jsx conditioning in render method of your splash screen and render different images accordingly, before that in componentWillMount method get the information about the language pre selected by user using asyncStorage which is stored when user selected the language, last time accessing the app.